# In iOS 7, refresh control is in the above of my tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, refresh

I created a UIViewController instance, and there was a UITableView instance as its' subview.
The I created a refresh control, tableview add it as a subview. The problem is in iOS 7, my refresh control is in the above of my tableview, here is a screenshot. And can you tell me how to fix this problem. Thanks a lot!
[image]

```
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]init];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshData) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.tableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
```

And I didn't use UITableViewController, i add a tableview as a subview of my superview.

Comment: Why you don't use MBProgressHUD its adjusted automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I don't think it's a good idea to use MBProgressHUD replace refresh control when I refreshing data.

Comment: Ok..would you like to show that refresh control at center? or top as per that screenshot? in short in which place refresh control you want to
 display?

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: I want to show the refresh control at the default position(center of screen top). And I have edited my post and show my code how to add a refresh control to the tableview, is there some thing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved!

In viewDidLoad method, use below code :

```
UITableViewController *tableVC = [[UITableViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
[tableVC setTableView:self.tableView];
tableVC.refreshControl = self.refreshControl;
```

Comment: [Thie question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461838/in-ios-7-refresh-control-is-in-the-above-of-my-tableview) _italic_ **bold**  `UITableViewController *tableVC = [[UITableViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
[tableVC setTableView:self.tableView];
tableVC.refreshControl = self.refreshControl;`